# How to send SIGINT to multiple processes

Tags: kill, signals, sigint

I am trying to send the SIGINT signal to multiple processes, I think this is right:

```
kill -2 <pid1> <pid2> ... <pid3>
```

but I cannot confirm that...

Comment: How could you test it?

Comment: that is a damn good question lulz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is right.  The man page confirms it.  Running `man kill` says:

```
SYNOPSIS
   kill [options] <pid> [...]

...

OPTIONS
   <pid> [...]
          Send signal to every <pid> listed.
```

Your shell probably provides its own internal version of `kill`, which will take precedence, but it should be compatible with the interface described.  You may be able to find more info by running `help kill`.

I'd use `kill -INT` instead of `kill -2`, since the name-to-number mapping can vary between UNIX variants.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue with my game server not saving, because it needed SIGINT instead of KILL and the number mapping was failing.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to test with program that generates a bunch of copies of itself, reacts to the signal, and sits around waiting for a signal:

```
% perl -E '$SIG{INT}=sub {say "ouch"};fork();fork();say $$;sleep 999'
17344
17346
17345
17347
ouch
ouch
ouch
ouch
```

Kurosawa wipe to the other terminal where a

```
% kill -2 17344 17346 17345 17347
```

was obviously run.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for i in <pid1> <pid2> <pid3>; do kill -2 $i; done
```

Or:

```
for i in {17344..17347}; do kill -2 $i; done
```